# What's the equivalent of the reciprocal pronoun 'each other' in Taqbaylit Berber (spoekn in Northern Algeria)?

Tags: syntax, pronouns

Berber languages spoken in Northern Africa show some degree of variation in relation to the reciprocal, but not the reflexive pronoun. For example, in northern Moroccan Berber (Tarifit), they say *ayawya* 'each other', but in the southern Moroccan Berber (Tashlhit), they say *ingratsen* again meaning 'each other'. I want to know which equivalent is used in Berber spoken in Northern Algeria (Taqbaylit), if there's anyone who speaks this variety? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All Berber languages use the reciprocal affix m(y)- (ssen/know > mssen/know each other). Some Berber languages have also developed, independently, a reciprocal pronoun.

For example, in Riffian, this reciprocal pronoun has this form: ay-a wy-a . But it is not the only reciprocal pronoun used in this language.

Some just don't have innovated and use only the reciprocal affix, as in Kabylian.

Finally, reflexive pronouns are not identical according to Berber varieties.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Do you know the equivalent?

Comment: They don't have reciprocal pronoun, as I wrote.

Comment: thank you, sorry I voted against your answer, I tried to revote again, it doesn't work..

Comment: can I ask a further question? Do you think 'm-sse.n' above is intransitive?

Comment: @Tsutsu T. Yes, if a transitive verb is changed into the middle voice, so it is converted into a intransitive verb (min ssnen/*min messnen or *min ssnen ayawya).

Comment: thank you, your answers helped :)

Comment: @Tsutsu T. Are you interested in opening a Berber language stackexchange ? https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: yes of course! it'll be a great thing, just tell me what to do. I'd love to see a website for all Berber linguists discussing issues. There's a lot to discuss :D

Comment: The instructions are given in the link that I gave you. Can you take on opening it?

Comment: yes I did, they explain how to do a Beta version and go with the requirements of optimality and technicality of other stackexchanges..